# Vim Highlight Setting Local

Tags: vim

I want to ask if it is possible to define highlighting local to a buffer/window, as well as with any other vim option. So far I've this small group in my `.vimrc`, to "highlight" the active window. Therefore only the active window gets the cursorline.

```
augroup CursorLine
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinEnter * set cursorline
  autocmd WinLeave * set nocursorline
augroup END
```

Now I want to do something similar with the background. A pure black for inactive windows and a really dark grey for the active one. My approach is this:

```
augroup BackgroundSwitch
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinEnter * highlight Normal ctermbg=235 ctermfg=15  guibg=#ff0000 guifg=#FFFFFF cterm=NONE  gui=NONE
  autocmd WinLeave * highlight Normal ctermbg=16  ctermfg=15  guibg=#ff0000 guifg=#FFFFFF cterm=NONE  gui=NONE
augroup END
```

Unfortunately this always make all window backgrounds like the active one. I guess WinLeave is thrown before WinEnter, so it is only rly shortly visible (not for me). An setting a highlight instead of an options, affects always all windows in this *Vim* instance.
So is there the possibility, that this highlights are only set locally, so I get the wished behaviour?
Thanks!

Comment: it is not that easy, unfortunaly. There is [this plugin](https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive) which does this with a little cheat. It just sets `colorcolumn` to every column in every inactive split. But that has other problems, this is just one of the limitations of vim.

Comment: Thnaks. Have took a quick look into the implementation. Looks quite exhaustive for such a simple thing. Are there any disadvantages (e.g. performance issues) by this plugin you know about?

Comment: I do not use it, but it says on the github page that redraw might be slower, you will have to try it

Comment: I'm already trying it. Not bad. What looks bad ist, that the `colorcolumn` highlight only affects the places, where text is. Makes it a bit inconsistent.

Comment: `:highlight` is always global.

Comment: @romainl Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Changing the highlight is always global and can't be changed only for
  a scope.
- The [Diminactive](https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive) provide a hack for this. But this plugin lacks in the following points:

  - The "background" is only changed in lines, which contains text (new line char included).
  - Background highlights like seach results in inactive windows are invisble (the whole result) and lead to ugly gaps within the text.
  - Makes the redraw theoretically slower, which sum up with all other plugins u might have run in background to process your buffers (not recognized on my computer).